# How to use ShemaSpyGui for view database diagram

Tags: database, postgresql, visualization, data-visualization

I installed Postgre today and I want to watch database shema.

I resolvse to  use schemaSpy and download it and also schemaSpyGui

[image]

and then I see:

[image]

```
This is the command (password not displayed!) SchemaSpyGUI has generated:
java -jar "D:\free\schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar" -dp "D:\free\postgresql-9.1-903.jdbc4.jar" -t pgsql -db marc_db -host localhost -port 5432 -u marc -connprops "D:\free\schemaSpyGUI20090302\properties\pgsql.properties" -o "D:\free\schemaSpyGUI20090302\marc_marc_db_"

Failed to query Graphviz version information
  with: dot -V
  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dot": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Using database properties:
  [D:\free\schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar]/net/sourceforge/schemaspy/dbTypes/pgsql.properties
Gathering schema details...

No tables or views were found in schema 'marc'.
The schema does not exist in the database.
Make sure that you specify a valid schema with the -s option and that
  the user specified (marc) can read from the schema.
Note that schema names are usually case sensitive.

3 schemas exist in this database.
Some of these "schemas" may be users or system schemas.

information_schema pg_catalog public 
These schemas contain tables/views that user 'marc' can see:

 information_schema pg_catalE=2og publicI=2
```

I have installed `Graphviz2.38`

And if from cmd I type

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin>dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
```

Please help.

### update

after advice in comment I added `path\to\Graphviz2.38\bin` to the `Path` environment variable and now I see following:

```
This is the command (password not displayed!) SchemaSpyGUI has generated:
java -jar "D:\freelance\db_things\schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar" -dp "C:\Users\redwhite\.m2\repository\postgresql\postgresql\9.0-801.jdbc4\postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar" -t pgsql -db marc_db -host localhost -port 5432 -u marc -connprops "D:\freelance\db_things\schemaSpyGUI20090302\properties\pgsql.properties" -o "D:\freelance\db_things\schemaSpyGUI20090302\marc_marc_db_"

Using database properties:
  [D:\freelance\db_things\schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar]/net/sourceforge/schemaspy/dbTypes/pgsql.properties
Gathering schema details...

No tables or views were found in schema 'marc'.
The schema does not exist in the database.
Make sure that you specify a valid schema with the -s option and that
  the user specified (marc) can read from the schema.
Note that schema names are usually case sensitive.

4 schemas exist in this database.
Some of these "schemas" may be users or system schemas.

information_schema pg_catalog pg_toast_temp_1 public 
These schemas contain tables/views that user 'marc' can see:

 informationE=2_sch emapg_catalog publicI=2
```

my shema looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to your Path so Java can find it from the directory is executing from (D:\free)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 now I have another problem. Can you help?

Comment: You should stick to one question per question.  Did adding it to the path solve your first problem or not?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 topic has updated

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 are you ready to help if I would create new topic?

Comment: The (new) error says it's looking for a Database (schema) named "Marc" and it doesn't exist.  Do you have one?

Comment: I have shema with name 'public' but as you can see field for shema is absent on ui interface

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 something like this http://joxi.ru/vn2Y8KzgfbzPm6.jpg?d=

Comment: Does the pgsql.properties file reference the Marc schema in it by any chance?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 looks like no http://joxi.ru/48AnXL0EIzPjmO.jpg?d=

Comment: It's seeing these schemas: information_schema, pg_catalog and public. Do any of those DBs in there have those schemas?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, marc_db has 'public' shema

Comment: Ok, maybe I should rephrase -- Do any of those DB's have all three of those schemas? :)  Or either of the ones listed that are not "public"?

Comment: If I right inderstood I have 3 databases. and each have only one shema with name 'public'. http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/141004/11b92257ad.jpg

Comment: Eventually I copied comand from error message and added ** -p password -s shema ** and executed it from cmd and I got a success

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin to my "Path" so Java can find it from the directory is executing from.